# How to improve the speed of deployment for a python based serverless framework project using Gitlab CI

Tags: python, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, serverless-framework

I'm trying to integrate my serverless project with an existing Git repository with a CI setup. The existing gitlab-ci.yml requires a docker image.

I'm new to Gitlab CI so I was playing around in a different git repository just trying to get it to work.

I've been able to get it to work with two different gitlab-ci.yml setups. However, there is a significant difference in speed.

Using an ubuntu image, it takes 6 minutes to deploy:

```
deploy-stage:
  stage: deploy
  image: ubuntu:18.04
  environment:
    name: stage
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y curl software-properties-common
    - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
    - bash nodesource_setup.sh
    - apt install -y nodejs
    - add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
    - apt install -y python3.8 python3-pip
    - cd db_update_campaigns
    - npm install
    - npm install -g serverless
    - sls deploy -v
```

I was then able to get it to work with a docker image (which is what I needed to do to integrate it with the existing git repository), however it takes 24 minutes to deploy:

```
deploy-stage:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:stable
  environment:
    name: stage
  script:
    - apk add --update python3 py3-pip python3-dev nodejs nodejs-npm build-base postgresql-dev
    - cd db_update_campaigns
    - npm install
    - npm install -g serverless
    - sls deploy -v
```

Does anyone know why there would be such a difference in speed?
Also, is there any way of improving the speed of deployment when using a docker image?

Any help on this would be appreciated. I'm a total beginner when it comes to this so any of your advice would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are installing dependencies required on each build. (All commands before `cd db_update_campaigns`). Those are not specific to the deployment of the current package and can thus be prepared beforehand, so that only the `npm install` and `sls deploy` commands need to be run on deployment.

To achieve this, first create a custom docker image, based on the docker:stable. This image should add all required dependencies:

```
FROM docker:stable
RUN apk add --update python3 py3-pip python3-dev nodejs nodejs-npm build-base postgresql-dev
```

Build and [push the image to a registry](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#pushing-a-docker-container-image-to-docker-hub) (for example dockerhub)

```
docker build -t <dockerhubusername>/myBuildImage:latest
docker push <dockerhubusername>/myBuildImage:latest
```

In your gitlab-ci.yaml reference your custom image instead of the vanilla docker one.

```
deploy-stage:
  stage: deploy
  image: <dockerhubusername>/myBuildImage:latest
  environment:
    name: stage
  script:
    - cd db_update_campaigns
    - npm install
    - npm install -g serverless
    - sls deploy -v
```

This should save you some time during deployment as the image does not need to install the dependencies every time.

If you prefer to use a private dockerhub registry or, a gitlab registry please see [Define an image from a private Container Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry) from the gitlab documentation for how to set that up